# MQTT Two way communication

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am interested in making communications of commands between different MQTT clients and to perform the regarding actions on both end. Is it possible to have two way communication using MQTT? I am working on Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 4):

Yes its possible by using different publisher and subscriber topic for same client. Also you need some handler on client side to act.

Comment: This answer is closer than the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by two way communication.  You have subscribers and publishers in Mqtt.  You could have a subscriber sitting out there listening to a particular topic and have it react to certain messages.

The way you would interact with that subscriber is by a publisher.  Have it send a message to that subscriber's topic it's listening on.

Answer (score 1):

A client that you have subscribing and publishing is actually initiating the communication in both cases. Since the broker is ack and responding, the broker need not know the IP address of the client since it responds back through the client's TCP path to the socket. This, to an extent assists in security of the client that is behind a firewall since the client does not need port forwarding for the reason mentioned.